# Are all EJBs deployed as JAR?

Tags: jar, glassfish, ejb, war, ear

When looking at how Netbeans uses ant to build an Enterprise Application, packaged as an EAR file:

```
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/build/lib

-do-ear-dist:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb/dist
      [jar] Building jar: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb/dist/netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb.jar

-post-dist:

dist-ear:

pre-pre-compile:

pre-compile:

-do-compile-deps:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/build

do-compile:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/build/META-INF

post-compile:

compile:

pre-dist:

do-dist-without-manifest:

do-dist-with-manifest:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist
      [jar] Building jar: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist/netbeansEnterpriseApp.ear

post-dist:

dist:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ tree
.
├── build
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── netbeansRemoteInterface.jar
│   ├── META-INF
│   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb.jar
├── build.xml
├── dist
│   └── netbeansEnterpriseApp.ear
├── nbproject
│   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   ├── build-impl.xml
│   ├── genfiles.properties
│   ├── private
│   │   └── private.properties
│   ├── project.properties
│   └── project.xml
├── netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── classes
│   │   │   ├── ejb
│   │   │   │   └── NewSessionBean.class
│   │   │   ├── META-INF
│   │   │   │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   │   └── netbeansRemoteInterface.jar
│   │   ├── empty
│   │   └── generated-sources
│   │       └── ap-source-output
│   ├── build.xml
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb.jar
│   ├── nbproject
│   │   ├── ant-deploy.xml
│   │   ├── build-impl.xml
│   │   ├── genfiles.properties
│   │   ├── private
│   │   │   └── private.properties
│   │   ├── project.properties
│   │   └── project.xml
│   └── src
│       ├── conf
│       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│       └── java
│           └── ejb
│               └── NewSessionBean.java
└── src
    └── conf
        └── MANIFEST.MF

23 directories, 25 files
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ asadmin deploy dist/netbeansEnterpriseApp.ear 
Application deployed with name netbeansEnterpriseApp.
Command deploy executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ asadmin list-applications
netbeansEnterpriseApp  <ear, ejb>  
Command list-applications executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp$ cd dist/
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ ls
netbeansEnterpriseApp.ear
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ jar xf netbeansEnterpriseApp.ear 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ ll
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 4 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 11 19:29 ./
drwxrwxr-x 7 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 11 19:28 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 11 19:28 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 11 19:28 META-INF/
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 2834 Nov 11 19:28 netbeansEnterpriseApp.ear
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir 1351 Nov 11 19:28 netbeansEnterpriseApp-ejb.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$ ll lib/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 11 19:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 11 19:29 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 thufir thufir  782 Nov 11 19:28 netbeansRemoteInterface.jar
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/netbeansEnterpriseApp/dist$
```

I notice that, when deployed to Glassfish, both EAR and EJB are listed.  On its own, an EJB is [packaged](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejdev003.htm) as a JAR?  There's no such thing as an EJB packaged as an EAR?  (Rather, any EJB packaged in an EAR or WAR ultimately is deployed as a JAR -- to my understanding.)

Or, are there EJB which are **not** deployed as JAR files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the EJBs in the WAR do not need to be packaged as Jar, if your applicationserver (as jboss7 and wildfly) supports this.
The ejb-classes can be found inside the WAR in WEB-INF/classes.

An example project used for tests you can find at [ejb-cdi-unit-test-war](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/tree/master/ejb-cdi-unit-test-war). If you try and clone you will need maven to build the project.